# Load numpy array to a Tensorflow dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to do image colorization. I have 5000 images (256x256x3) and would like not to load all data in my program (for memory reason). I have found that it is possible to use `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` but I use LAB images and I would like to feed my model with a numpy array of the L component (256, 256, 1). My targets are A and B components (256, 256, 2). To have my image I then merge the input and output to have a LAB image (256, 256, 3). The problem i that `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` only works with image type files (so a 256x256x3 image) and I would like to know if there is a way to do the same thing with numpy arrays.

I tried using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()`, I had all my files but I did not found how to load my numpy array to feed my model. I guess I need to use some sort of generator but I do not really understand how to use it. This is what I have for now :

```
HEIGHT = 256
WIDTH = HEIGHT
Batch_size = 50

dir_X_train = 'data/X_train_np/train_black_resized/*.npy'
dir_X_test = 'data/X_test/test_black_resized/*.npy'
dir_y_train = 'data/y_train_np/train_color_resized/*.npy'
dir_y_test = 'data/y_test/test_color_resized/*.npy'

X_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dir_X_train, shuffle=False).batch(Batch_size)
y_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dir_y_train, shuffle=False).batch(Batch_size)

def process_path(file_path):
  return tf.io.read_file(file_path[0])

X_train_dataset = X_train_dataset.map(process_path)
y_train_dataset = y_train_dataset.map(process_path)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_train_dataset, y_train_dataset))

for image_black, image_color in train_dataset.take(1):
   print(image_black.numpy()[:100])
   print(type(image_black))
   print(image_color.numpy()[:100])
   print(type(image_color))
```

Output :

```
b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '<f4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (256, 256), }                           "
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '<f4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (256, 256, 2), }                        "
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

The shape seems to be correct but I don't know how to have the `numpy.array`

Comment: check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simpler way to handle batch inputs from tfrecords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrecords)

Comment: @V.M wouldn't that still load everything into memory? If so, OP might as well just use numpy arrays as input directly. (even though they said they'd like to not load all in their program)

Comment: It doesnt. The above creates tfrecords. And you can set `buffer_size`, to how much data can be loaded.

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388725/7746219

Comment: @MohammadAhmed I tried your methode but my `model.fit` wont work :
`ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.`

Comment: Hi @Evermus, you can use `np.load()` and `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to load numpy array to a Tensorflow dataset. Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/7c67e3c31c597ee8238672d63b9a9b0a/74492503.ipynb#scrollTo=gOeufSgms2IX). Thank you!

Comment: @Tfer3 I tried using that but I can not fit my model, it consider my input as a Tuple and I get the following error : `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: @Evermus, please try casting the dataset using `np.array(list(dataset))`. Thank you!